# PHP file_exists and wildcard

Tags: php, wildcard

Is there a way to write the PHP file_exists function so that it searches a directory for a file with an arbitrary extension.  For instance, suppose I knew that a file were called "hello", but I didn't know the extension, how would I write a function that searched for a file called hello.* and returned the name of this file?  As far as I can tell, file_exists will only search for a string.

Thanks.

Comment: *(related)* http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test/

Answer (score 110, accepted):

**You're looking for the [`glob()`](http://fr.php.net/glob) function.**

`file_exists` doesn't do any kind of search : it only allows one to know whether a file exists or not, when knowing its name.

And, with PHP >= 5.3, you could use the new [**`GlobIterator`**](http://fr.php.net/globiterator).

As an example with `glob()`, the following portion of code :

```
$list = glob('temp*.php');
var_dump($list);
```

Gives me this output :

```
array
  0 => string 'temp-2.php' (length=10)
  1 => string 'temp.php' (length=8)
```

While this one :

```
$list = glob('te*-*');
var_dump($list);
```

*Yes, with two `*` ;-)*

Will give me :

```
array
  0 => string 'temp-2.php' (length=10)
  1 => string 'test-1.php' (length=10)
  2 => string 'test-curl.php' (length=13)
  3 => string 'test-phing-1' (length=12)
  4 => string 'test-phpdoc' (length=11)
```

Comment: I knew there must have been a better function for this.  Thank you!

Comment: Also note that you're not restricted to `*`; single characters (`?`) and classes (`[abc]`) to name a few can also be put to good use in glob patterns.

Comment: Just a small addition: the glob() function gets its name from the globbing used in Linux shells (like Bash). https://linuxhint.com/bash_globbing_tutorial/

Answer (score 9):

As of PHP5.3, you can also use the [`GlobIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php) to search a directory with wildcards:

```
$it = iterator_to_array(
    new GlobIterator('/some/path/*.pdf', GlobIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME) );
```

would return the full paths to all .pdf files in some/path in an array. The above performs about the same as `glob()`, but iterators provide a more powerful and extensible API.

Answer (score 6):

As long as file_exists returns a BOOLEAN I wrote this small function
that accepts a search string with * to look for files...
Example:

```
    searchForFile("temp*");

    function searchForFile($fileToSearchFor){
        $numberOfFiles = count(glob($fileToSearchFor));
        return ($numberOfFiles > 0);
    }
```

Comment: Works like charm. Side note: you might need to add the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] part to the front of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a little more control and are on pre PHP 5.3 you could use a DirectoryIterator or RecursiveDirectoryIterator. Both have a lot of great function for added control and manipulation.

PHP docs are at [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fnmatch` to match one filename against a pattern. Use this in a loop over all files.

```php
if (fnmatch("hello*", $filename)) {
  echo 'true';
}
```