# How to check if file name exist without know the file format php

Tags: php, file

```
if(file_exists("/img/korica/Design_1.*"))
    echo "file exist";
else
    echo "there are no files with that name"
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746364/php-file-exists-and-wildcard) might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scandir();

```
$files = scandir("/path/to/directory");
print_r($files);
```

another example:

```
<?php

$files = array_filter(scandir('/path/to/directory'), function($item) {
    return $item !== '.' && $item !== '..';
});

foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    if(file_exists("path/to/directory/$filename"))
    {
        echo "file exist\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "file doesn't exist\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [`:glob()`](https://www.php.net/glob) :

```
$existence= glob("./Yourdir/filename.*");
```

And then check if `$existence` has something or not!

It can also be used with a `bash-like` brace expansion:

```
glob("./uploads/filename.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE).
```